# Json in javascript and jquery cannot get the value of the item by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get('url', function(msg){
        entirePage = JSON.stringify(msg);

        text=(JSON.parse(entirePage));
         console.log(text.productid);
       console.log(text['productname']);


    });
    });
</script>
```

the result is like the following:

[image]

but if i try this code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get('url', function(msg){
        entirePage = JSON.stringify(msg);
        text=(JSON.parse(entirePage));
         console.log(text);
    });
    });
```

I have the following result:
[image]

Comment: How do you create json.

Comment: i used php code:    $myObj->productid = $all_product->getproductid();
    $myObj->productname = $all_product->getproductname();
    $myObj->detial = $all_product->getdetail();
    $myObj->image = $all_product->getimageurl();

    $myJSON=json_encode($myObj,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   echo $myJSON;

Comment: From the console logs it seems that `text` is a string not an object. Get rid of the `entirePage` variable and use just `text = JSON.parse(msg)`

Comment: Why are you serializing then deserializing the input ? You are doing unnecessary operations

Comment: @Titus, I get this error: VM1882:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 2902
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Use the Network tab and check the full response. Make sure there's nothing before or after the JSON. Sometimes there are error messages or HTML.

Comment: Network tabs is fine, and I have everything there, but I need to get some html tag inside the json, because I create json from mysql database.

Comment: is the output of `console.log(msg)` a JSON string or a JS object ?

Answer (score 2):

```
const myArrStr = JSON.parse(msg);
    console.log(myArrStr[0].productid);
```

that is it, but make sure you do not have extra things when you create your json.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the `msg` is of type string or object using `type of` operator before parsing.

I'm not sure why you're stringifying and parsing the same `msg` object and trying to get some of the properties from it.

If you're just interested in just getting the properties of the returned object. Check the type and proceed..

```
jQuery.get('url', function(msg) {
    if (typeof msg === 'string') {
        msg = JSON.parse(msg); // you can write a try-block-catch in case if its not a valid JSON
    }

    // additionally check for typeof msg === 'object'
    let productId = msg.productid; // you can add extra check using text.hasOwnProperty('productid'); if not sure
    let productName = msg.productname;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thank you my problem solved by the previous answer.